# Largest prime factor

Tags: java

I have a little problem with my java code! The question is: The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

My code somehow doesn't work!! What's wrong? Thanks for your help!

```
public class Example_1 {

    public static void main (String[] args){
    {
        System.out.println(largestPrimeFactor(600851475143));   
    }
}

private static long largestPrimeFactor(long number) {
        long result = 0;

        for(long x = 2;x<number;x++){

            if(number % x == 0){
                for( long y = 2; y < x ; y++ ){
                    if( x % y == 0){
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        result = x;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `largestPrimeFactor` is outside of the class. It is not like that in your actual code right? Besides, main method has two `{` in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

```
for( long y = 2; y < x ; y++ ){
    if( x % y == 0){
        break;
    }
    else{
        result = x;
    }
}
```

Here you are trying to test whether `x` is prime. However, if you follow this loop logic through, you will see that it translates to the following:

- If any `y` is found not to be a factor of `x` *before it is discovered whether or not `x` is prime*, then `x` is prime.

Refactor the `else` to outside the loop.

```
boolean xIsPrime = true;

for( long y = 2; y < x ; y++ ){
    if( x % y == 0){
        xIsPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}

if( xIsPrime ){
    result = x;
}
```

Compilation problems:

- The method `largestPrimeFactor` appears to be outside of a class.
- The constant `600851475143` is too large for an int. Postfix with `L`: `600851475143L`.

Note that the algorithm you've written is suboptimal and that is why it may run for a long time when given large inputs.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Example_1 {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(largestPrimeFactor(600851475143L));   
    }

    private static long largestPrimeFactor(long number) {
        long result = 0;

        if (number % 2 == 0){
            result = 2;
            while (number % 2 == 0)
                number /= 2;
        }

        for(long x = 3; number > 1; x += 2)
            if (number % x == 0){
                result = x;
                while (number % x == 0)
                    number /= x;
            }

        return result;
    }

}
```